# jquery- showing column value in alert message

Tags: jquery, asp.net

1. I have made a simple table using table tag and  and  tags
2. There are 5 rows with column names as empID, empName and Button1
3. The last column of the table has a button in each row, on click event of which I want:
   An alert message saying HI .
   Ex: If the empName in first row is "john", & if I click on button of that row, an alert message should pop up showing "Hi john".
4. I am not getting how to show the empName dynamically inside the alert message.

PLEASE HELP !!

Comment: show us what you have tried so far. At least post your html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1c1cmvwb/1/)

```
$(function(){
    $("button").on("click", function(){
        var name = $(this).parent().parent().find("td:eq(1)").text();
        alert("Hi " + name);
    });
});
```

Comment: I would prefer to use `$(this).closest("tr").find("td:eq(1)").text();`

Comment: you are right. This is better solution. Let me update the code.

Comment: finally!!! it worked!! thanks a ton sanjay!!! i was using children. can you please explain what is this eq(1) ???

Comment: If you say find("td"), it will return all tds in that tr. So with :eq, you can specify which td (index of the element) you want. see [this](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) documentation for more detail.

Answer (score 1):

try

### **HTML**

```
<table style="width:100%">
    <tr>
        <td>Jill</td>
        <td>Smith</td>
        <td>
            <button>button</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Eve</td>
        <td>Jackson</td>
        <td>
            <button>button</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**JS**

```
 $("button").click(function () {
    alert($(this).closest("tr").find("td:first").text());
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/yy7j0xLy/1/)